# Kali Linux: apt update returns "Hash Sum mismatch" error

Tags: kali-linux, hashsum

I'm experiencing exactly the same issue as described in this question: [Kali Linux: apt-get update returns “Hash Sum mismatch” error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382617/kali-linux-apt-get-update-returns-hash-sum-mismatch-error). Before you mark this as a duplicate however, I have tried the solutions posted there, as well as on numerous other sites, including:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` with alternate official mirrors, such as 
`deb http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib` or `deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib`

Everything worked after I first imported the VM. I ran `sudo apt update` and it found some ~650 packages to upgrade. I ran `sudo apt upgrade` and it encountered an error partway through. That error was solved using `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, but that is when this hash sum error began. Unfortunately due to hours of troubleshooting I no longer have the details of the earlier error, but I believe it was an error extracting a package due to corrupt data.

I've tried multiple official mirrors, but I get the same error. Additionally, when I downloaded the Packages.gz file [here](https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz) on my Windows machine (VM host) and computed the SHA256 hash, I got the exact hash that `apt` printed as the expected value. This led me to believe that the error was not with the mirror but with my VM.

The next thing I tried was `wget https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz` followed by `sha256sum Packages.gz`, which provided yet another different hash output.

To be clear, I have seen 3 different hashes for the same file:

1. The "correct" hash shown by `apt` as expected, which is the one that windows also produced after downloading the file using a browser
2. The incorrect hash calculated by `apt`, which led to the error
3. A different hash calculated by `sha256sum` after downloading the file using `wget` using the same URL as for the browser download

I should also note that I have only been referencing the SHA256 hash in each step. The other hash functions are also mismatched when I run `sudo apt update`, but the file size is the same. I had considered that downloads might be failing due to limited disk space (it is a VM after all) but I don't think that's the case.

What am I missing?

Comment: Flatten it and install from scratch. It's a pen-testing distribution so you shouldn't have anything of value on it anyway.

Comment: That was my thought as well. Unfortunately I re-imported the .ova and got the same issue. So I tried installing into a fresh VM using an installer iso, and the install failed at the package selection step (not sure if it's the same cause).

Comment: Maybe it's a virtualbox issue I suppose, now that I'm typing this comment.

Comment: It's possible it's a transient fault in one or more of the mirrors.

Comment: I had the same issue. Check out [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241893/594870), he solves it. Particularly for Windows 10 host using Virtualbox. For me when I asked that question, some packages worked fine but Docker was one that did not. The key is [disabling Hyper-V and getting rid of that Green Turtle](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=90853&sid=dd153bd7f58ac95966ee195414bdf7a5&start=270#p476261)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QUICK FIX:

- Shut down Kali VM.
- Run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` in CMD.
- Reboot.

EXPLANATION:

This issue is caused by the Windows Hypervisor Platform.
This issue cannot be resolved for now (as far as I know).

A partial fix is at hand though. And I say "partial" because it involves disabling the platform (also known as "Hyper-V") which  will probably break other virtualization solutions you have installed since this is enabled manually.
Anyway, here's how to disable it and get your Kali VM running again;

1. Shut down the Kali Virtual Machine.
2. Press Windows logo key + X, then hit A to run Command Prompt as
   administrator.
3. Type `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
4. When you see "The operation completed succesfully", type `reboot`

After reboot, boot Kali and update/upgrade.

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you very much, nothing else did work, but this simple solution worked for me.

Comment: bcedit is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh you missed a letter its **bcdedit**

Comment: For Mac VMWare, this worked for me: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Kali-Linux-apt-update-returns-Hash-Sum-mismatch-error-Fusion-12/m-p/2824396/highlight/true#M172116

Comment: I'm 2.5 years late, but that you @DenHeldert for your answer! Apparently I have not logged in for a long time.